# on click open chrome history in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to add a button on my website, to do this function on click show chrome history?

```
<a class="myclas" onclick="chrome://history/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img class="myclass" src="//myimg.png" width="16" height="16" />  History</a>
```

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: ok thanks for your help.

Comment: use href instead of onclick , it will be work

Comment: I tried it before but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

chrome://history/ is just an regular url, try this:

```
<a class="myclas" href="chrome://history/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img class="myclass" src="//myimg.png" width="16" height="16" />  History</a>
```

Comment: I tried it before but it does not work, Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, looks like Chrome block it because I tried: `location.href="chrome://history/"`and put the url into an iframe and I get: `Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://history/` for both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help